# separate serial numbers for related records?

Tags: field, relational-database, sequence, filemaker

Normally a serial number would work where a record gets created and it can auto create that number in the sequence for all records regardless.  What I'm trying to determine is whether there's any way, perhaps a calculated field could work, where there's a separate sequence number that can start from 1 for records in a relation to a parent record (key = key).  For example, key=11 has child records that have sequence fields starting from 1, and similar to key=12 or any other number respectively.

Any help or guidance on this question shall be gratefully appreciated as we want to display a rank in those order as created.

Comment: Why would you need this? Note: a calculation field *could* work - but then if you delete a record, the numbers will recalculate.

Comment: while random sequence numbers (ie. 2, 7, 9 instead of 1,2,3) could work, but we need a way to physically order them the latter way for display purposes..

Comment: For display, you can sort them by creation order (i.e. unsort) and number them *ad hoc* using either Get (RecordNumber) or a summary field that counts.

Comment: I'll give Get(RecordNumber) a try, thanks.